# Regex for matching script tags that contain a specific string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

In Node.js, I am trying to pull specific script tags from an HTML file. The file has many script tags, but only some of them contain a push() method call. I only want to match those. I have linked a super simplified example Regexr that is close. I need this to not match the first three lines as part of the first match though.

The current regex: `<script\b[^>]*>([\n\r\s\S]*?)push([\n\r\s\S]*?)<\/script>`

Example:
https://regexr.com/3qqt8

Comment: Is using regex necessary? Standard DOM manipulation would be far easier

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is being done in Node.js. No DOM present. I updated the post to clarify.

Comment: You could use [JSDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cleaning job. Building on your existing code, I suggest capture and disregard script-blocks without the push-keyword in an alternation, and then just work with the values stored in the capture groups. This could look like this:

```
<script\b[^>]*>(?:(?!push)[\s\S])*?<\/script>|<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)push([\s\S]*?)<\/script>
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LpWXsR/1/)

You may want to use a stronger definition of your keyword, e.g. `\.push\(` to avoid false positives.

```js
var regex = /<skript\b[^>]*>(?:(?!push)[\s\S])*?<\/skript>|<skript\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)push([\s\S]*?)<\/skript>/g;
var str = `<skript>
function() {}
</skript>
<div></div>
<skript>
someFuncCall();
array.push();
</skript>
<skript>
otherFuncCall();
array.push();
</skript>
`;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
      if(m[1] && m[2]) // if group 1 & 2 exists
        console.log(`Found: ${m[1]}push${m[2]}`);
    
}
```

PS: It looks like script-tags are filtered out in snippets, thus I've replaced them with *skript*-tags.